# How to remove ghost lines in Chartjs?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a multi yaxis timeseries chart. Some of the yaxes start at non zero values somewhere in the middle of the timeseries. I noticed ghost lines which on the chart for those datasets.

I have tried setting `beginAtZero` attribute to `false` (which is the default value anyway)

How do I get rid of them?

Here is a code snippet which shows `chart options` and `data` attributes of the `chart` object.

```
let chartPropertyOptions = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        type: 'time',
        display: true,
        distribution: 'linear',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'DD MMM YYYY'
          }
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        display: false,
        id: 'date'
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        id: 'axis0',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Axis 0',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: true,
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 40,
          min: 5
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'axis1',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Axis 1',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: true,
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 40,
          min: 5,
          beginAtZero: false
        },
        display: false,
      },
      {
        id: 'axis2',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Axis 2',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: true,
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 40,
          min: 5
        },
        display: false,
      },
      {
        id: 'axis3',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Axis 3',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: true,
        position: 'left',
        ticks: {
          max: 40,
          min: 5
        },
        display: false,
      },
      {
        id: 'axis4',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Axis 4',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        stacked: true,
        position: 'right',
      }
    ]
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  responsive: true
};
let data = {
            labels: response.data.map(a => a.date),
            xAxisId: 'date',
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Axis 0',
                data: response.data.map(a => a.v1),
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'yaxis0',
                borderColor: '#fe8b36',
              },
              {
                label: 'Axis 1',
                data: response.data.map(a => {
                  let result = a.v1_mean + a.v1_std*2;
                  return result;
                }),
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'yaxis1',
                borderColor: '#ff0000',
              },
              {
                label: 'Axis 2',
                data: response.data.map(a => {
                  let result = a.v1_mean - a.v1_std*2;
                  return result
                }),
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'yaxis2',
                borderColor: '#002ef4',
              },
              {
                label: 'Axis 3',
                data: response.data.map(a => a.v1_mean),
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'yaxis3',
                borderColor: '#a06ee4',
              },
              {
                label: 'Axis 4',
                data: response.data.map(a => a.v2),
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'yaxis4',
                borderColor: '#a43fe4',
              }
            ]
          };

let chart = new Chart(myChartRef, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: chartPropertyOptions
          });
```

[image: Ghost lines when yaxis values start at non zero.]

Comment: I also tried setting `spanGaps: false` in datasets. This didn't work either.

Comment: possible to create a jsfiddle or something equivalent?

Comment: @cdoshi It's difficult, I am using my local DB to fetch the data.

Comment: can you hard code the minimum possible data required to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Never-mind. I understood the problem. I have some `null` data values for `v1_mean` which were being used in this `let result = a.v1_mean - a.v1_std*2;` which results in a non null value. Hence they get plotted on the chart.

Comment: glad you worked it out!